# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function eregi(), 2 passed in

Tags: php, wordpress

I upgraded the PHP version from PHP 5.3 to PHP 7.4 and facing errors.

```
if(!function_exists('ereg'))            { function ereg($pattern, $subject, &$matches) { return preg_match('/'.$pattern.'/', $subject, $matches); } }
if(!function_exists('eregi'))           { function eregi($pattern, $subject, &$matches) { return preg_match('/'.$pattern.'/i', $subject, $matches); } }
if(!function_exists('ereg_replace'))    { function ereg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string) { return preg_replace('/'.$pattern.'/', $replacement, $string); } }
if(!function_exists('eregi_replace'))   { function eregi_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string) { return preg_replace('/'.$pattern.'/i', $replacement, $string); } }
```

An error appears on this line:

```
if (eregi($urlregex, $URL)) { if($debug == "true") { logtofile("Debug :".$URL." is a valid URL."); } return $URL; }
```

Error is

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
> function eregi(), 2 passed in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bank\livechat\Code\library\jqSajax.class.php on line
> 171 and exactly 3 expected in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bank\livechat\Code\include\main_pre_body.php:5

I changed eregi() to preg_match() like this

```
if (preg_match($urlregex, $URL))
        {
            if($debug == "true")
            {
                logtofile("Debug :".$URL." is a valid URL.");
            }
            return $URL;
        }
        else
        {
            if($debug == "true")
            {
                logtofile("Error :".$URL." is not a valid URL.");
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Now it shows this:

> "**Warning**: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '?' in
> **C:\xampp\htdocs\bank\livechat\Code\library\jqSajax.class.php** on
> line **171**
> "

Thanks

Comment: which regular expression triggers this error ? can you try `var_dump($urlregex)` ?

Comment: It shows this error if var_dump using (eregi($urlregex, $URL))
https://imgur.com/rRzFN0Q

Comment: and C:\xampp\htdocs\bank\livechat\Code\include\main_pre_body.php on line 5 is this
https://imgur.com/dtSBpcO

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'eregi' ) ) {
    function eregi( $pattern, $subject, &$matches ) {
        return preg_match( '/' . $pattern . '/i', $subject, $matches );
    }
}
```

in your first snippet, which defines the function with 3 arguments, but then you have:

```
if ( eregi( $urlregex, $URL ) ) {
    if ( $debug == "true" ) {
        logtofile( "Debug :" . $URL . " is a valid URL." );
    }
    return $URL;
}
```

in your second snippet, which calls the function with only 2 arguments.

So you need to supply all 3 arguments, like:

```
if ( eregi( $urlregex, $URL, &$matches ) ) {
    if ( $debug == "true" ) {
        logtofile( "Debug :" . $URL . " is a valid URL." );
    }
    return $URL;
}
```

Comment: But the confusion is what should be the $matches?

Comment: Do you mean what does the variable contain? It's passed by reference, so that'd depend on where it's coming from elsewhere in your code...

Comment: Perhaps this will help you - `$matches` contains the result, so I'm not sure what you're asking... https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php